# Bootstrap Datepicker:Disable date range from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, bootstrap-4, datepicker

Does exist any possibility to disable date ranges from database? For example, I have date range
**from 15.01.2021 to 21.01.2021** and **from 24.01.2021 to 03.02.2021** and I want to disable these dates in datepicker and you couldn't be able to select from let's say **from 17.01.2021 to 25.01.2021** but you can select **from 22.01.2021 to 23.01.2021**.

Comment: Do you want to set some disabled date ranges in the database and then disable them in Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes.Database would be like booking_id, from_date, to_date.

Answer (score 0):

## Database

On your database you could create a `table` of the like of **invalid_interval(id, from, to)**. Store the invalid intervals and load it at your server-side, so you can serve the client-side by sending out this information.

## Client-side

When you initialize your date picker, you can set your disabled dates like this:

```
    var disabledDate = ['2020-1-1', '2020-1-15','2020-1-3'];

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({

        disabledDates: disabledDate

    });
```

Read more [here](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/bootstrap-datetimepicker-disable-dates-dynamically). So, the attribute you were looking for is `disabledDates` and you can pass an array to it.